# Can't force reload Angular page when clicking on link to the current page

Tags: angular, routes

According to [this blog](https://blog.angularindepth.com/refresh-current-route-in-angular-512a19d58f6e), I should be able to use `onSameUrlNavigation` property of my router. However, the following setup seems not to work.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: "", component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "counter", component: CounterComponent },
  { path: "fetch-data", component: FetchDataComponent },
  { path: "**", component: ErrorComponent }
], { onSameUrlNavigation: "reload" })
```

The intellisense suggested the property so I'm assuming that it's placed in the correct part of the code (also, mimicing [the blog](https://medium.com/engineering-on-the-incline/reloading-current-route-on-click-angular-5-1a1bfc740ab2)).

I'm not getting any error messages and, frankly, I have no idea how to approach it. (The version of Angular is 7.2, so it's above 5.1 as required.)

Perhaps there's a simpler approach for my goal? I simply want all the links in my navbar to reload the contents of the page. I can set a method to fire when clicked but it seems a bit clunky, especially if there's a built-in, best-practice method for that in Angular.

Comment: Something you may find interesting: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21115

Comment: @R.Richards I interpret the contents of the link that it's not going to re-init the component and that it's so by design. I find it most intuitive that clicking a link will cause the same load-in of the contents but apparently, Google's developer  disagree. I prefer not to introduce additional complexity by using guards and resolvers. Am I to understand that it's the only proper way?

Comment: That does seem to be the case. A little unfortunate.